# Google App Engine OSError: cannot load library 'libsndfile.so'

Tags: python-3.x, docker, google-app-engine, streamlit

I get the following error from Google App Engine after completing a docker push.

> OSError: cannot load library 'libsndfile.so': libsndfile.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

My docker file has the following:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    software-properties-common \
    ffmpeg \
    libsndfile1-dev \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Which should get that library. I also found that pip installing soundfile might also fix it but that did not work either.

I am pushing a Streamlit app if that helps at all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it'll be solved, but why don't you add `gcc`?

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    gcc \
    software-properties-common \
    ffmpeg \
    libsndfile1-dev \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```